# How to handle setInterval in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, setinterval

I have a timer in my component, which is running with `setInterval` that starts in `mounted()` component.

Suppose this component is at `http://localhost:3000/some-route`.
Now how do I do `clearInterval()` whenever I go to another route like `http://localhost:3000/` as I want to stop the timer.
I've used `unmounted()` but when you go to different route, the component doesn't unmounts but if I go to same route (`/some-route`), `setInterval` runs again as the component is mounted again.

So, how do I clear the interval every time I go to different route?

Comment: To my knowledge, `unmounted()` does not exist. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do it once, it's a bit tricky because of the scope and the way it interacts with `this` (arrow functions basically). At the end, I also needed it to be available globally so I used it in pair with Vuex but you can totally use it in a component with some upper scope for the variable.

Here is a sample of code I've used

```js
actionSetPolling({ state, dispatch }) {
  try {
    const myPolling = setInterval(async function () {
      if (someVariable !== 'COMPLETED') {
        // do stuff
      } else if (conditionToStop) {
        // this is facultative, but can be done here so far too
        window.clearInterval(myPolling)
      }
    }, 2000)
    dispatch('setPollingId', myPolling)
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('error during polling', error.response)
    window.clearInterval(state.pollingId)
  }
}
```

`setPollingId` is an action that set's a `pollingId` mutation, that way I can track it all along globally.

You could use the same while unmounting your component with this

```js
beforeDestroy() {
  window.clearInterval(state.pollingId)
},
```

Not sure if it's the best way of doing things but `setInterval` is by it's nature, clunky and hacky out of the box IMO, especially in an SPA.

Comment: OMG. Yes the problem was I was using umounted() which is actually in vuejs 3.0 and not in nuxt which I think uses vuejs 2.0 lifecycle hooks. Anyways I have successfully cleared the interval in destroyed(). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq yep, Nuxt is currenly only available in it's Vue2 form. Nuxt3 (with Vue3) support is coming soon.